# Can ShareGate tell how old a document is even if it's been recently moved?

Tags: document-library, migration, document-migration

I'm using ShareGate to migrate c. 50,000 documents from a drive to a SharePoint Library. I want to remove all files over 3 years old. Unfortunately the originating drive was imported from an older system just two years ago meaning that all documents look to be less than 2 years old even though many documents are up to 7 years old. Can ShareGate identify the original date of the document even though the 'properties' have been updated by the original migration?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this: https://documentation.sharegate.com/hc/en-us/articles/17813814906644-ShareGate-s-migration-tool-FAQ

When you migrate content with date and time values like `Created` and `Modified`, ShareGate's migration tool copies the underlying SharePoint time value.

If the properties of the document have been updated by the original migration, it might not reflect the original date of the document.